# Embedding music player in django project

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I'm facing a task when I need to embed music player in a django blog application. The problem is that I rely do not know where to start whit this, first time implementing such a thing. The documentation on the internet are lame on this one, and I'm having hard time thinking of how to approach this problem.

Question is:

Can any one explain to me how can I embed such a thing into mine blog project, and how to make Django handle this music player, is it wise to use angularjs on this one, perhaps?

From where to start?

Answer (score 7):

You're not very clear about what you exactly want to do.

I'm assuming you want to upload audio files to your blog and have a player on your html.

One of your models will need to have a [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield), so you can upload your audio files.

**models.py**

```
class Song(model.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=125)
    audio_file = model.FileField()
```

Than in your view, obviously pass the song object to the template, and in your template use an [audio-element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

**template.html**

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="{{ song.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 3):

check out [HTML5 Audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

All you have to do is pass the model object to template via view... Then give the correct path

Comment: Is there a possibility that you make me a small example,  just something to think about, and I will chek Html5 audio.

Comment: @user1797792 posted nice example.. What stopping you ?

Comment: Nothing,  I'm not at home, it's a great example, I just wanted something to think about before I come home and start working on it, thanks